# Creating a HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase from a UserAgent string

Tags: c#, .net, http

So the [HttpRequestBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.aspx) class has a [Browser property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.browser.aspx) that returns a [HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilitiesbase.aspx).  We currently use this property in some of our MVC infrastructure code to get things like the Browser name and version number (for output to logs).

We also have an api that uses [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/), and I would like to be able to hook this into our existing infrastructure.  The only thing missing is being able to parse the browser name and version out of the UserAgent header (which I have thanks to the IHttpRequest.UserAgent), but need a way to parse it.

My question - is it possible to create a HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase somehow with just a UserAgent string?  The only available subtype I see on msdn is [HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilitieswrapper.aspx), whose sole ctor is another HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase.

I was thinking that this class probably solely parses the UserAgent string anyways, so why isn't there a ctor(string)??  Is there a subtype, factory or static method I am not seeing that can accomplish this?

Generally I am just doing this for laziness - I don't want to write/find another UserAgent parser when I know .Net has that capability they are just hiding it.

Comment: HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase is abstract so you're not going to be able to create an instance at all.

Comment: Yes but HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper is the only inheritor on msdn, whose sole ctor takes another HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper.

Comment: There has to be a concrete other than the wrapper *somewhere*..

Comment: Use a decompiler for .NET (like JustDecompile) to see how the framework does the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had to do this myself. Here's what I tried. It's decompiled from `System.Web`, but is still dependent on that library. I'm still testing it, but maybe it helps you:

```
public class BrowserCapabilities
{

    public static HttpBrowserCapabilities 
        GetHttpBrowserCapabilities(NameValueCollection headers, string userAgent)
    {
        var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
        var browserCaps = new HttpBrowserCapabilities();
        var hashtable = new Hashtable(180, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        hashtable[string.Empty] = userAgent;
        browserCaps.Capabilities = hashtable;
        factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(headers, browserCaps);
        factory.ConfigureCustomCapabilities(headers, browserCaps);
        return browserCaps;
    }
}
```

To test:

```
var features = BrowserCapabilities.GetHttpBrowserCapabilities(null, 
    "Mozilla/4.0    (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
Console.WriteLine(features.Browser);
```

Comment: I think this solution will throw a NullReferenceException on the line: factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(headers, browserCaps); when there is no found definition for the useragent.  For example I used: "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 830)"