# C# Mock Request.Browser.MajorVersion using RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rhino-mocks

I have the following code in an MVC controller:

```
        var isIe6 = Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("IE") && Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 7;
```

I need to stub out the second part using Rhino Mocks. I have tried this:

```
HttpRequest.Stub(a => a.Browser).Return(new HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper(new HttpBrowserCapabilities
        {
            Capabilities = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"majorversion", "11"},
                {"MajorVersion", "11"},
                {"browser", "IE"},
                {"isMobileDevice","false"}
            }
        }));
```

The above code returns 0 for the `MajorVersion` in the code. I have also tried this:

```
HttpRequest.Stub(a => a.Browser.MajorVersion).Return(11);
```

Which just throws an exception on setup saying Browser needs to be set. I've also tried it in combination with the `HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper` above, but it still says Browser needs to be set.

How do I stub/mock out Request.Browser.MajorVersion in MVC?

Some test code if anyone needs it:

```
    private BasketController sut;
    protected HttpRequestBase HttpRequest;

    [Test]
    public void ShowsMajorVersionDoesNotWork()
    {
        // Arrange
        HttpRequest.Stub(a => a.Browser).Return(new HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper(new HttpBrowserCapabilities
        {
            Capabilities = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"majorversion", "11"},
                {"MajorVersion", "11"},
                {"browser", "IE"},
                {"isMobileDevice","false"}
            }
        }));
        //HttpRequest.Stub(a => a.Browser.MajorVersion).Return(11); // Throws Exception
        sut = new BasketController()
        {
            Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(HttpContext, new RouteData()), new RouteCollection())
        };
        sut.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(HttpContext, new RouteData(), sut);


        // Act
        var result = sut.Method();

        // Assert
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("11")); // Fails, always returns 0
    }
```

Method under test in BasketController:

```
    public string Method()
    {
        return Request.Browser.MajorVersion.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] (i.e. the simplest unit test which shows the issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the `HttpBrowserCapabilities`using `BrowserCapabilitiesFactory` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253724/creating-a-httpbrowsercapabilitiesbase-from-a-useragent-string)), using the [IE11 user-agent string](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11s-many-user-agent-strings/), and similiarily you can mock any other browser `MajorVersion` with the correct string:

```
public HttpRequestBase GetInterenetExplorer11StubRequest()
{
    return GetBrowserCapabilitiesStub("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
}

public HttpRequestBase GetBrowserCapabilitiesStub(string userAgentString)
{
    var browser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities
    {
        Capabilities = new Hashtable { { string.Empty, userAgentString } }
    };
    var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
    factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), browser);
    var request = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpRequestBase>();
    request.Stub(a => a.Browser).Return(new HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper(browser));
    return request;
}
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer when it compiles for me, the last line is wrong

Comment: Good point! I've updated the code to create HttpRequest stub with stubbed Browser property